# Is there any grammatical error in "He denied to help me"?

Tags: grammar

> He denied to help me.

I am confused whether the above sentence is correct or not.

Comment: I think a more idiomatic way to say the sentence is to say "he denied my request for help." If you insist to say the way you did, you better use "refuse" instead of "deny": He refused to help me.

Comment: 'deny' is used when you say you didn't do what you're being accused of. For example - He denied killing the woman.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why am i getting down voted for this question?

Comment: I think the down votes are because you didn't look up "to deny" in the dictionary and explain why you're still confused about how the verb is used.

Comment: You also haven't explained the context. "He denied to help me" is wrong, but we can't determine whether you mean "He denied helping me" or "He declined to help me".

Answer (score 1):

If you use a verb after the verb *deny* you would expect a gerund not an infinitive ...

"He denied stealing" not "He denied to steal"
"He denied running" not "He denied to run"

With the gerund the denial centres on the subject - "He denied that he had stolen" "He denied that he had run"

So, if we put the gerund after ...

"He denied helping" we see it actually means that "He denied that he had helped", which isn't what you are trying to say.

So, as Sasan commented, to say what you are meaning to say you need to change how you express what was denied ("my request for help"), or change the verb "deny" to one that will take the infinitive you want to use ("He refused to help me").

Which one you use will depend on the context of the statement.